# How to close a Bootstrap 3 dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to close a Bootstrap 3 dropdown if it's open.

I thought about using `$( '#mydropdown' ).dropdown( 'toggle' )` but that doesn't help because if the dropdown is currently closed I don't want it to toggle open.

How can I modify my code so that it checks to see if the dropdown is open before executing the toggle method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $( '#mydropdown' ).hasClass( 'open' ) )
    $( '#mydropdown' ).removeClass( 'open' );
```

This is the solution I went with. It simply removes the `.open` class if the dropdown has it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use:

```
$( '#mydropdown.open .dropdown-menu' ).dropdown( 'toggle' )
```

it simply select dropdown if it is opened and then close it.

Because js add that class to your dropdown element

There is no open / close method in documentation... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage

Comment: The problem I have then is if I want to open the dropdown again, let's say via a click, it doesn't seem to open. Please see my answer I've just come up with, it seems to be working well.

Comment: yop, you are right, I edited my answer, you should be called toggle method on dropdown-menu :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a http://jsfiddle.net/?

From bootstrap documentation

> Via data attributes or JavaScript, the dropdown plugin toggles hidden
>   content (dropdown menus) by toggling the .open class on the parent
>   list item

Use simple if else to check if the class exists:

```
if($(".dropdown").hasClass(".open")){
    $( '#mydropdown' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );
}
else{
    //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the click event manually

```
$('.navbar').click(); or
$('.navbar').toggle('click');
```